# derivative of projector onto positive semidefinite cone is independent of the choice of orthogonal matrices

Tags: matrices

We know that when projector onto positive semidefinite cone $K$ is differentiable at $X$ then its derivative is
$D \Pi_K(X)[H]= Q f^{(1)}(\lambda) \circ (Q^T  H Q) Q^T$,

where $X=Q \lambda Q^T$ is eigenvalue decomposition of $X$, 
$f(x)=[x]_+$,

$ (f^{(1)}(d))_{ij}= \left\{\begin{array}{ll} \cfrac{[d_i]_+ - [d_j]_+}{d_i - d_j} & \text{if}\; d_i \ne d_j \\
f'(d_i) &\text{if}\; d_i =d_j. \end{array} \right.$

We note that $f'(x) =\left\{\begin{array}{ll} 1 &\text{if} \; x>0\\
 0 & \text{if} \; x<0  \end{array} \right.$.

I try to explain why the formula of the derivative does not depend on the choice of orthogonal matrices $Q$, but have no idea. Would you please help me?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please provide some reference for the expression for the projector differential and conditions for when it is differentiable?